# Marklogic 6 Index creation?

Tags: indexing, xquery, marklogic

I have used to `Xquery` for getting attribute value but this query little bit slow.

Can you please suggest me which `indexing` should be help to speedup the Query?

```
**Sample Xquery**
//root/root1[@name eq "antony"] /@dept
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `//`. This will select nodes anywhere in the tree with the path `/root/root1[@name eq "antony"] /@dept`. If possible try `/root/root1[@name eq "antony"] /@dept`
For indexing, you can put a attribute range index on `@name`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is using `cts:search` and create `indexing` through `MarkLogic` to `Attribute Range Indexes` instead of having path which is really slow. 
Also, you can query your index by: 
`cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("root1"), xs:QName("name"), "=", "antony")`